# "disabled" style on cocoa text labels using bindings

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm using Cocoa bindings (in Swift) to implement a preferences pane. Some of the settings only apply when other settings are turned on. This is mostly on check boxes, where its easy to use.

For instance, you can only "add a default name" when "add a default number" is turned on. This is easy to do by binding the enabled state on one check box to the same setting as the value in the other. Presto.

Now some of the prefs are not check boxes, but combos or text fields. These are labeled using NSTextFields, which also have an enabled binding. However, when these are disabled, the display does not change. I'd *really* like the text to become "disabled style" too, like it does on the checkbox.

So, does anyone know of a way to make this happen? There is a Text Color binding, but I'm not sure how I would use that in this case, at least without writing separate methods for every such example in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a value transformer class (subclass of `NSValueTransformer`) which transforms a boolean to a color. You can then apply that value transformer to a binding of a label's text color binding to a boolean property (presumably the same one that you're using to disable related controls).

Comment: Thanks Ken, this set me down the right path. There is some confusion on how to use these in Swift, but after a few tries I got it to work perfectly. Definitely one for my snippets pile!